How to suppress heavy outline of selected cell in WxGrid?
My program has a wx.grid.Grid that has a selection mode of GridSelectRows.  When the user clicks on it, the entire row is selected, which is what I want.  However, the cell on which the user has clicked gets drawn with a heavy outline, implying that it has the focus or something.  I do not want a cell to be set apart from the others; I want all cells in the row selected equally.  How can I suppress this heavy-outline behavior?
This is what the grid looks like when it is presented to the user:

This is how it is displayed when the user clicks.  In this case, the user has clicked on the fourth row of the Shares column.  Note the heavy white outline.

If the grid loses focus, the row is still selected (yay!) and no cell appears to have any special highlight (also yay!):

If the user uses an arrow key when a row in the grid has been selected, the selection goes away and another cell (presumably where the grid believes the user has "moved" to) has a heavy black outline.  Here, the user has hit the left arrow key:

I don't want that.  Maybe if the user used the up- or down-arrow keys it might be nice if the selection moved, but if the user hits left-arrow or right-arrow, the selection should remain the same.  I want entire rows to be selected and to have the focus, not individual cells, ever.  Is there some flag or something that will give me the behavior I want?  I haven't found any.
[I think this question is language- and platform-agnostic, but for what it's worth I'm using wxWidgets v3.0.1 on Windows 10, using perl 5.28 and Wx module 0.9932]

Calling SetCellHighlightPenWidth(0) and SetCellHighlightROPenWidth(0) might help with this.

That looks like it has potential.  Unfortunately, my Wx library doesn't have that method.  I may have to upgrade.
